# Jest typescript request-progress pipe not flushed

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I implement this functionality from request-progress in a Jest test.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var progress = require('request-progress');

async function downloader()
  Promise(resolve, reject) => { 
    // The options argument is optional so you can omit it
    progress(request('https://az412801.vo.msecnd.net/vhd/VMBuild_20141027/VirtualBox  /IE11/Windows/IE11.Win8.1.For.Windows.VirtualBox.zip'), {
    // throttle: 2000,                    // Throttle the progress event to 2000ms, defaults to 1000ms
    // delay: 1000,                       // Only start to emit after 1000ms delay, defaults to 0ms
    // lengthHeader: 'x-transfer-length'  // Length header to use, defaults to content-length
    })
    .on('progress', function (state) {
        console.log('progress', state);
    })
    .on('error', function (err) { 
        // Do something with err
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        // Do something after request finishes
    })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('IE11.Win8.1.For.Windows.VirtualBox.zip'));
  }
)
```

However, the pipe is not flushed at the end of the transfer. When the test exits after 'await'-ing the downloaded file is a about 1k or so less that the correct filesize. So I have to presume a lost flush.

If I run a more complicated set of function after the download then the file is the correct size. This is how i have heuristicly identified the problem as a lost flush.

Is there a way to force the flush on the filestream in on('end' ... ) or another method ?

Alternatively I could add a wait, but its hacky and I dont like it.

If I put the resolve in the .on('end') I dont get the last flush.

If I dont include a resolve then the function never returns.

Is it possible to put it on the pipe ?

Comment: Can you share your test code, where this is used? You'll likely need an async test that signals completion via the `on('end'` callback.

Comment: I will add what I can

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit to Jest / Node framework being new to me. But what worked after some iterations was

.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fname).on('finish', () => {resolve();}));